# Jfrog file upload failing with 403 forbidden

Tags: rest, artifactory, http-status-code-403, jfrog-cli

I have been trying to upload a file into JFrog artifactory repo from the cli as below and keep getting the 403 Forbidden error. What am I missing as env variables, etc for the upload to go through from the cli?

```
jf rt u "xyz" --url="http://example.com/ui/repos/tree/General/asdf/cba" --username="afad" --password="********"

Log path: /home/asdf/.jfrog/logs/jfrog-cli.ss.ss.ss.log
[Info][Thread 2]Uploading artifact: xyz
[Warn][Thread 2](Attempt 1) - Failure occurred while uploading to http://example.com/ui/repos/tree/General/asdf/cba/--username=svc@esuk.com/xyz: 
server response: 403 Forbidden
[Warn][Thread 2](Attempt 2) - Failure occurred while uploading to http://example.com/ui/repos/tree/General/asdf/cba/--username=svc@esuk.com/xyz: 
server response: 403 Forbidden
[Warn][Thread 2](Attempt 3) - Failure occurred while uploading to http://example.com/ui/repos/tree/General/asdf/cba/--username=svc@esuk.com/xyz: 
server response: 403 Forbidden
[Warn][Thread 2](Attempt 4) - Failure occurred while uploading to http://example.com/ui/repos/tree/General/asdf/cba/--username=svc@esuk.com/xyz: 
server response: 403 Forbidden
[Info] [Thread 2] executor timeout after 3 attempts with 0 milliseconds wait intervals
[Error] server response: 403 Forbidden
[Error] Failed uploading 1 artifacts.
[Error] server response: 403 Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

`--username` is not a valid argument and the target path is also missing. Use the below command to upload a file.

```
jf rt u "testfile.txt" "generic-local"  --url="https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory" --user="youruser" --password="yourpassword"
```

This will upload a file called testfile.txt to the repository generic-local. If you want to deploy to a specific path, you can pass the path after generic-local.

```
jf rt u "testfile.txt" "generic-local/path1/subpath/"  --url="https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory" --user="youruser" --password="yourpassword"
```